# Run a query based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a query based on multiple checkboxes.  This is a snippet of the checkboxes on the form.

```
<td><strong>
        <input name="criteria[Buffet]" type="checkbox" id="Buffet" value="1"/>
        <label for="Buffet">Buffet</label>
        </strong></td>
      <td><strong>
        <input name="criteria[Breakfast]" type="checkbox" id="Breakfast" value="1"/>
        <label for="Breakfast">Breakfast</label>
        </strong></td>
      <td><strong>
        <input name="criteria[BYOB]" type="checkbox" id="BYOB" value="1" />
        <label for="BYOB">BYOB</label>
        </strong></td>
```

This is the php script on the result page....

```
<?php
require "congig.php";
if(isset($_POST['criteria']) && !empty($_POST['criteria'])){ 
    foreach($_POST['criteria'] as $key=>$value){ 
        if($value==1) $criteria[] = "'DetailName'='".mysql_escape_string($key)."'";
        } 
        $criteria = implode(' OR ', $criteria); 
        } 
        if(!$rs=mysql_query("SELECT tblLocations.CityID, tblRestaurants.RestName, tblLocations.Street,          
        tblLocations.Phone, tblLocations.Price, tblLocations.Rating, tblDetails.DetailName
        FROM (tblRestaurants INNER JOIN tblLocations ON tblRestaurants.RestID = tblLocations.RestID)            
        INNER JOIN (tblLocDet INNER JOIN tblDetails ON tblLocDet.DetailID = tblDetails.DetailID)
        ON tblLocations.LocationID = tblLocDet.LocID
        WHERE tblLocations.CityID='16'
        AND $criteria
        ORDER BY tblRestaurants.RestName ASC"))
        {
echo "Cannot parse query";
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
echo "No records found";
}
else {
echo "<table id=\"myTable\" table width=\"710\" class=\"beautifuldata\" align=\"Left\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
echo "<th>PLACE</th>";
echo "<th>ADDRESS</th>";
echo "<th>PHONE</th>";
echo "<th>PRICE</th>";
echo "<th>RATING</th>";
echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo"<tr>
<td><strong><a href='$row[RestPage]'>$row[RestName]</a></strong></td>
<td>$row[Address]</td>
<td>$row[Phone]</td>
<td>$row[Price]</td>
<td>$row[Rating]</td>
</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table><br />\n";
}
?>
```

Any suggestion on why I am not getting any results?

Comment: i am too tired to check documentation so not adding this as a answer but i would have done this:
`<input name="criteria" type="checkbox" id="Buffet" value="buffet"/>
<input name="criteria" type="checkbox" id="Breakfast" value="breakfast"/>
<input name="criteria" type="checkbox" id="BYOB" value="byob"/>`

Comment: This looks like 10x the amount of code that you should ever need for something like this.

Comment: working on a solution, just a few more mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your problem appears to be the fact you're surrounding the column `DetailName` in single quotes: `"'DetailName'='"` when all it should be is `"DetailName='"`

On a note of security, I would like to point out that the function `mysql_escape_string()` you're using to force input to be mysql-friendly is old and riddled with security holes. Instead, I'd recommend using the much safer implementation: `mysql_real_escape_string()`. The code examples below make use of the newer, safer function.

Separate from those issues however, I'd recommend taking a slightly different approach which will be easier to read and much easier to manage in the long run.

For starters, I'd recommend using the same name on all checkboxes, and using the DetailName as the value rather than as the key:

```
<td>
    <input name="criteria[]" type="checkbox" id="Buffet" value="Buffet" />
    <strong><label for="Buffet">Buffet</label></strong>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="criteria[]" type="checkbox" id="Breakfast" value="Breakfast" />
    <strong><label for="Breakfast">Breakfast</label></strong>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="criteria[]" type="checkbox" id="BYOB" value="BYOB" />
    <strong><label for="BYOB">BYOB</label></strong>
</td>
```

Next, using the values of your inputs rather than the keys, we can now generate our clause. Very efficiently:

```
// Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
$clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['criteria']);
// Convert the array into a string.
$criteria = implode("','", $clean_criteria);
```

Finally, in your query, I'd recommend using the `IN` operator rather than the `OR` operator for efficiency and readability:

```
SELECT
    tblLocations.CityID, tblRestaurants.RestName, tblLocations.Street, tblLocations.Phone, tblLocations.Price, tblLocations.Rating, tblDetails.DetailName
FROM
    (
        tblRestaurants
    INNER JOIN
        tblLocations ON tblRestaurants.RestID = tblLocations.RestID
    )            
INNER JOIN
    (
        tblLocDet
    INNER JOIN
        tblDetails ON tblLocDet.DetailID = tblDetails.DetailID
    ) ON tblLocations.LocationID = tblLocDet.LocID
WHERE tblLocations.CityID='16' AND tblDetails.DetailName IN ($criteria)
ORDER BY tblRestaurants.RestName ASC
```

Here is the whole PHP side of things combining the modifications I suggest with your logic:

```
<?php
require "congig.php";
if(!empty($_POST['criteria'])) { // empty() checks if the value is set before checking if it's empty.
    foreach($_POST['criteria'] as $key=>$value){ 
        // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
        $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['criteria']);
        // Convert the array into a string.
        $criteria = implode("','", $clean_criteria);
    }

    $rs = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            tblLocations.CityID, tblRestaurants.RestName, tblLocations.Street, tblLocations.Phone, tblLocations.Price, tblLocations.Rating, tblDetails.DetailName
        FROM
            (
                tblRestaurants
            INNER JOIN
                tblLocations ON tblRestaurants.RestID = tblLocations.RestID
            )            
        INNER JOIN
            (
                tblLocDet
            INNER JOIN
                tblDetails ON tblLocDet.DetailID = tblDetails.DetailID
            ) ON tblLocations.LocationID = tblLocDet.LocID
        WHERE tblLocations.CityID='16' AND tblDetails.DetailName IN ($criteria)
        ORDER BY tblRestaurants.RestName ASC
    ");
    if(!$rs) {
        echo "Cannot parse query";
    } else if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
        echo "No records found";
    } else {
        echo "<table id=\"myTable\" table width=\"710\" class=\"beautifuldata\" align=\"Left\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
        echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
        echo "<th>PLACE</th>";
        echo "<th>ADDRESS</th>";
        echo "<th>PHONE</th>";
        echo "<th>PRICE</th>";
        echo "<th>RATING</th>";
        echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            echo"<tr>
            <td><strong><a href='$row[RestPage]'>$row[RestName]</a></strong></td>
            <td>$row[Address]</td>
            <td>$row[Phone]</td>
            <td>$row[Price]</td>
            <td>$row[Rating]</td>
            </tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table><br />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am changing everything back.  I will return with results!

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I changed everything and still, I am getting the same results.  Nothing.  If you wish, you can go to this link.  Ignore everything except the checkboxes.  Check off "Fireplace" then SEARCH, and it just hangs there.  The link...http://www.menuhead.net/Steelers/deep_search.php

Comment: Also had to add a few curly brackets at the end.  I hope they are in the right place, otherwise I was getting an error.  }}}
  echo "</table><br />\n";
  }
  ?>

Comment: does that SQL query work for certain? i'm seeing some pretty insane joins happening there. unfortunately, i don't know your database schema so i can't determine if there is a logical error there. sorry about the lack of curly brackets, btw i fixed that. might want to try now, perhaps the brackets were in the wrong place before?

Comment: Joshua!  Thank you so much.  I changed AND DetailName IN ($criteria)
 to AND tblDetails.DetailName IN ('$criteria')
 and it now works!  Thank you once again.  Hey just one question?  What do you you mean by crazy joins on the tables.  I would love to learn a better way being that I'm still kind of new,  Once again, thank you.

Comment: Joshua, One other question. If I run two or more checkboxes, it's giving me the restaurants that have each of the criteria as opposed to a restaurant that meets the two or more criteria. How can this be reworded so that the results are not seperated.

Comment: Glad you've made progress! If I understand your question correctly (please mind I haven't tested this...) I'd remove `, tblDetails.DetailName` from your SELECT (is it needed in the result?) and replace `SELECT` with `SELECT DISTINCT`. This may not fit your use case though, so make sure you do a lot of testing and compare against the database entries to make sure you're not displaying results you shouldn't be. You can catch me on Google Chat/Gmail: jdburnz@gmail.com