# Multiple checkbox values, which are retrieved from a database with a query, are not being displayed for an (unknown) reason

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

So lately i have been working on a way to post values from a database through checkbox selecting. Thanks to a previous question: [How to use checkboxes to retrieve specific data in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527975/how-to-use-checkboxes-to-retrieve-specific-data-in-a-database/25528503?noredirect=1#comment39859183_25528503), i managed to get it working!

Although i got it working, i wanted to make my queries a bit more effective when multiple checkboxes are selected instead of writing queries with if/else for every checkbox possibility.

Through some research on stack overflow, this topic in particular: [Run a query based on multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717406/run-a-query-based-on-multiple-checkboxes), i created the code for my own project. Though, for some reason it just wont output the data correctly, it even wont output anything at all.

So i looked in my code to see where stuff goes wrong. I passed in several echo's to get array information etc, but it all seems ok EXCEPT the last echo where i am echoing the query results (which returns 0).

So i am kinda stuck now since i cant figure out what goes wrong. 
*NOTE*: It is for wordpress so that explains the little difference in querying.*

The code is as follows: 
**The HTML Code to display the checkboxes**

```
<form method="post">
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select Authors</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Barry" />Barry</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Henk" />Henk</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Nicolas" />Nicolas</li>      
        </ul>
    </div>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The ID is for a Jquery dropdown effect.

**The PHP code is as follows:**

*The code below defines the column titles that are being displayed/echo'd in a table

```
$column_names = array(
    "Authorss" => "Authorss",
    "Research_Source" => "Research_Source",
    "Research_Title" => "Research_Title"
);
$sql_columns = array();
    foreach($column_names as $i) {
        $sql_columns[] = $column_names[$i];
    }
```

The next lines of code checks the checked checkbox values and queries the selected values:

```
if(!empty($_POST['columns'])) { // empty() checks if the value is set before checking if it's empty.

    foreach($_POST['columns'] as $key=>$value){ 
    // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
        $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['columns']);

        // Convert the array into a string.
        $criteria = implode("','", $clean_criteria);


    }
    $tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT"
            .implode(",", $sql_columns)."

        FROM           
            wp_participants_database

        WHERE 
            authorss IN ($criteria)

        ORDER BY 
            authorss ASC
    "); 
}
```

If non is selected the query selects all possible results (this still has to be created tho since i want the specific select query to work first):

```
else {
    echo 'still needs to be edit to show everything here';
    //$tmp = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ".implode(",", $sql_columns)." FROM wp_participants_database;");       
    }
```

Now comes the part where the queried data is being showed/put in tables:

```
echo "<table>
    <tr>";

    foreach($column_names as $k => $v) {     
        echo "<th>$v</th>";             
    }
echo "</tr>";

if(count($tmp)>0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($tmp);$i++){
        echo "<tr>";  
            foreach($tmp[$i] as $key=>$value){
                echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";                 
            }           
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

*****UPDATE*****
Got it fixed myself! First i deleted:

```
 $column_names = array(
        "Authorss" => "Authorss",
        "Research_Source" => "Research_Source",
        "Research_Title" => "Research_Title"
    );
    $sql_columns = array();
        foreach($column_names as $i) {
            $sql_columns[] = $column_names[$i];
        }
```

This above code was unnecessary as the columns were all preset, so i just echo'd them by typing them out.

The problem was the following:

```
$tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT"
                .implode(",", $sql_columns)."

            FROM           
                wp_participants_database

            WHERE 
                authorss IN ($criteria)

            ORDER BY 
                authorss ASC
        ");
```

The $criteria variable should give a string to the IN, though in my code it was parsed as an literal (so no string). It seemed very easy, i just had to add the '' so it would be parsed as a string. Result: `WHERE authorss IN ('$criteria')`

Comment: Have you checked the query by printing it?

Comment: @senk Yep, print $tmp prints out the word: Array

Comment: No @Nicolas, just print the sql query string alone and check that you formed query correctly

Comment: @senk Im not a very good php'er/sql and its probably kinda stupid but i got no real clue what you mean. I have replaced the select implode in the query with a specific column name and the $criteria in the WHERE with a specific name (that is in the database). When i do this the query seems to work so the problem seems to be in either the $criteria var or the implode line. When i add ONLY the implode back (and leave the specific WHERE name) it doesn't work, but when i ONLY add the $criteria it still doesn't work.. so i can conclude both aren't working?

Comment: @senk nevermind i got it fixed, check the update. Thak you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div>
    <?php
        $corpServicesValue = $row['corp_services'];
        $value= explode(",",$corpServicesValue);

        if(in_array("1",$value))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="corporationServices[]" value="1" checked >Management<br>'; 

        ?>
</div>
```